# Converting linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given a linear congruence $x + a ≡ y $ mod $n$, is it valid to rewrite as $x - y ≡ a $ mod $n$ ? Based on the definition of congruence, $n | x + a - y$ if we have the expression $x + a ≡ y $ mod $n$ and $n | x - y - a$ if we have the expression $x - y ≡ a $ mod $n$

Comment: Yes, this follows immediately from the linked [Congruence Sum Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), i.e. add $-a-y$ to both sides of the congruence (or subtract $a$ then $y).\,$ Conceptually it is better to learn these *arithmetical* laws which allows us to manipulate congruences just as we do equations (vs. rewrite them as divisibility relations).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is

$$x-y\equiv -a(\text{mod }n)$$

You can perform addition and subtraction using modular arithmetic just as you would like, but the signs remain important.