# Potential modular-arithmetic mistake in CS StackExchange

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I asked a question regarding modular arithmetic in CS StackExchange website but think that there are critical mistakes in the modular arithmetic. The following is the link to the question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129527/shortest-path-in-modular-arithmetic/129538#129538.

For the original question, we can reinterpret: x and y connects iff $x + a ≡ y$ mod $n$. The answer rewrite the above congruence $x - y ≡ a$ mod $n$. If we apply addition modular arithmetic, we should get $x - y ≡ -a$ mod $n$. Also, if the above conversion is correct, how does the answer get $x + ma ≡ y$ mod $n$ from $x - y ≡ a$ mod $n$. If both operations are incorrect, how can we play with modular arithmetic to solve this problem?

Comment: You misread: they rewrite $\ x\color{#c00}{{\bf -}a}\equiv y\ $ to $\ x-y\equiv a.\ $ Or, equivalently, negate $\,a.\ $ Based on your [prior (essentially dupe) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3801855/242) I highly recommend  you review the basic congruence arithmetic laws linked there.

Comment: $a\equiv-a\bmod \mathbf 2$

Comment: @J.W.T But it's $\!\bmod 7\,$ not $\!\bmod 2,\ $ and it's better to learn the general idea.

Comment: $x + m a \equiv y\pmod{\!n}$ comes from a path of length $m$ between $x$ and $y$, i.e. start at $x$ then take $m$ steps of length $a$ to reach $y$, on a (modular) clock of $n$ hours.

Comment: As here, when you have questions about a specific answer it is usually best to first pose them in comments on the answer. If you don't receive an adequate reply then you can post a new question. That way you may help to improve the answer.